Question about the definition of a convex subset by interval
I am reading the Functional Analysis lecture notes by Hörmander and he defines a convex subset of a vector space on page 12

The definition I learned before is that a subset $A$ is convex if
$$
\{tx + (1-t)y: t\in [0,1]\}\subset A
$$
for any $x,y\in A$. A point is convex by the second definition but I am not sure whether it is convex by the first one.
Just to clarify, the first definition says that the set
$$
\{t\in\mathbb{R}: x + ty\in A\}
$$
is an interval. Do we allow it to be an empty interval? If yes, then I think the two definitions might coincide. Otherwise not...

You are right. I deleted my answer.

The set $L(x,y) = \{ x + ty \mid t \in \mathbb R\}$ is a line in $V$ unless $x = y = 0$ in which case it is $= \{0\}$.
Hörmander considers the sets $I(x,y) = \{t \in \mathbb R \mid x + ty \in A\}$.

If $x \ne 0$ or $y \ne 0$, then there is a bijection $b_{x,y} : I(x,y) \to L(x,y) \cap A, b_{x,y}(t) = x + ty$. Since $L(x,y) \cap A$ may be empty, also $I(x,y)$ may be empty.
If $x = y = 0$, then either $I(0,0) = \mathbb R$ (which happens if $0 \in A)$ or $I(0,0) = \emptyset$ (which happens if $0 \notin A$).

Therefore the requirement that $I(x,y)$ is an interval for all $x, y  \in V$ indeed only makes sense if $\emptyset$ is considered as an interval.
Formally one can say that for $a \in \mathbb R$ the set $(a,a) = \emptyset$ is an interval.
One can alternatively define an interval to be a subset $I \subset \mathbb R$ such that for all $x, y \in I$ with $x < y$ also all $z \in \mathbb R$ with $x < z < y$ belong to $I$. This is satisfied by $I = \emptyset$. A nonempty subset $I  \subset \mathbb R$ is clearly an interval in the sense of this definition if and only if it is an interval in the "usual sense". Note that one-point sets $\{a\}$ are intervals in the sense of our definition and "degenerate" closed intervals $[a,a]$.
